# CADisplayLink forward declaration error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compiler-errors, ios5, cadisplaylink

Okay, so I've been completely stumped by this compiler error for hours, and the problem is that all the googling I've done says it should work the way I have it!  I'm following a book tutorial for iPhone game development, and I got stuck on the second chapter because of a random compiler error.

**NOTICE: I am currently running and testing in XCode 4.1 with iOS 5 beta**

Here's the declaration:

In header file:

```
@interface GameController : NSObject
{
    CADisplayLink *displayLink;
}

@end
```

In the .m file

```
- (void)startGame {
    displayLink = [displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update:)];  // THROWS ERROR
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];  // THROWS ERROR
}

- (void)update:(CADisplayLink *)sender {
    // TODO: actually do something..
}
```

Both of these throw the error: Receiver 'CADisplayLink' for class message is a forward declaration

But all the posts online have the line exactly the same.  The error type is a 'Automatic Reference Counting Issue'.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` at the top of your source file, and link the QuartzCore framework if you haven't already done that.

Answer (score 3):

Have you added the QuartzCore framework to your project and the related import to this class?

`CADisplayLink` comes from that framework.